# ExcelADO. Table name. Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)'. Acc2013x64

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've successfully used ExcelADO for reading and importing Excel data into MSAccess during long time reading the entire SpreadSheet.

This time I need to import some table objects that can coexist with other table objects in the same spreadsheet.

According to the documentation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973, the only thing that needs to be changed is the From clause in the SQL string:

```
oRS.Open "Select * from Table1", oConn, adOpenStatic
```

However this fails and shows the error number mentioned in the title of this thread that essentially says that the object Table1 does not exists in that spreadsheet.

The complete code I'm using is this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx;" & _
         "Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes';"

    rst.Open "Select * From Table1", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    With rst
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
        Do Until .EOF
        Debug.Print .Fields(0), .Fields(1), .Fields(2)
        .MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

As I said I can retrieve the whole content of the spreadsheet using:

```
.Open "Select * From [Sheet1$]", oConn, adOpenStatic
```

Also I can get the contents of a specified range:

```
.Open "Select * From [Sheet1$A1:B10]", oConn, adOpenStatic
```

I double-checked for the existence of that object using VBA, and it's there:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim xlAp    As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb    As Excel.Workbook
    Dim i       As Long

    Set xlAp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWb = xlAp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx")
    For i = 1 To xlWb.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count
    Debug.Print xlWb.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(i).Name, _
            xlWb.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(i).DisplayName
    Next i
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlAp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Edit:

Well, the error is right in the sense that my object Table1 is not present in the schema as evaluated by using:

```
Set rs = cnn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    With rs
        If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
            Do Until .EOF
                Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), _
                            rs.Fields(1), _
                            rs.Fields(2), _
                            rs.Fields(3)
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

nor in the tables catalog:

```
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As ADOX.Table

Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
    cat.ActiveConnection = cnn
    For Each tbl In cat.Tables
        Debug.Print tbl.Name, tbl.Type
    Next tbl
Set cat = Nothing
```

That's strange considering that the [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) explicitly says:

> Named ranges are treated as "Tables" and worksheets are treated as "System Tables,"

So my guess is that Excel 2013 x64 stores named ranges in a different way than before and for accessing them via ExcelADO the syntax needs to be modified in the best scenario or they cannot accessed this way anymore.

As I previously said, the named ranges exist in my spreadsheet and I can loop through them using the range object via automation.

Hopefully someone has an answer to this.

All the best,

Diego

Environ: Windows 7 x64, Access 2013 x64, Excel 2013 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Norie from utteraccess put me in the right path:

> In Excel ListObjects aren't named ranges, and what you have is a
>   ListObject so it's not going to appear in the schema.

So this has nothing to do with the change in the object model; listobjects and named ranges are just different objects even if they appear almost the same for the user.

Didn't find an answer yet for dealing with ListObjects via ExcelAdo, but since that's another question I leave it here: [ExcelADO: Fill recordset with ListObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032539/excelado-fill-recordset-with-listobject)

Answer (score 0):

I have facing the same issue too. I have named range on another sheet that I can query using the named range.

When I open my Name Manager, there is sheets name that have single quote on the name, then query using named range on this sheet will not working.

Then I rename my sheet, then try query again and it's working.

I think my sheets name before conflict with excels default names, which is my sheets name on name manager have single quote